# select objects dynamically in code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have an xaml page with 40 rectangles, (4x10 grid), all named in the format r1-1 through to r10-4.

I would like to iterate through these in code:

```
        for (int row = 1; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col < 4; col++)
            {
                 ...// what do I need here
            }
        }
```

Any help please?

Comment: You can use the VisualTreeHelper to find controls. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you try to use the FindName() method : this.FindName("r"+row+"-"+col) ?

Comment: @Cubi thanks... how did I miss that!

Comment: You are welcome. I posted an answer with this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get dynamically an element by its name using the following :

```
for (int row = 1; row < 10; row++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col < 4; col++)
    {
        var elt = this.FindName("r" + row + "-" + col);
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I wouldn't recommend doing this, you can simply iterate through all of the items in the `Grid Panel` if you have a reference to it. Try something like this:

```
foreach (UIElement element in YourGrid.Children)
{
    // do something with each element here
}
```

Comment: A good recommendation here. Iterate through necessary control only.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your control by type or by name:

*By type*:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate through the Visual Tree:

```
foreach (Rectangle r in FindVisualChildren<Rectangle>(window))
{
    // do something with r here
}
```

*By name*:

```
for (int row = 1; row < 10; row++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col < 4; col++)
    {
        var control = this.FindName(string.Format("r{0}-r{1}", row.ToString(), col.ToString()));    
    }
}
```